# Apex Trigger for Adding Contacts to Campaigns as Campaign Members

Tags: apex, trigger, campaign, campaign-member

I am writing an Apex Trigger that will take the `Primary_Contact__c` from an `Opportunity` that has been `Closed Won` and the `Amount != Null` and add that `Contact` to a `Campaign` called `Closed Won`.

`Primary_Contact__c` is a Lookup field to the `Contact` object and has a relationship name of `Primary_Contact__r`.

Below is the code that I currently have. It is not throwing any errors it is just not adding the `Contact` to the proper `Campaign` upon saving of the record.

```
trigger UpdateClosedWonMembers on Opportunity (before update) {
List<CampaignMember> members = new List<CampaignMember>();

for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
    if (opp.StageName == 'Closed Won' && opp.Amount != Null) {
        CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember(CampaignId = '7011a000000BBny', ContactId = opp.Primary_Contact__r.Id, Status = 'Sent');

        members.add(cm);
    }

    try{
        insert members;
    } catch(DmlException e) {
        System.debug('An unexpected error has occured: ' + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @Ratan Please re-read the question. I stated that it is not throwing any errors. It is simply just not working.

Comment: In triggers, you won't have the values of Relationship fields. So opp.Primary_Contact__r.Id will be null. Use opp.Primary_Contact__c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the error has to do with context:

```
CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember(CampaignId = '7011a000000BBny',
                      ContactId = opp.Primary_Contact__r.Id, Status = 'Sent');
```

When the trigger executes the values of lookup fields are not available in `Trigger.new`. If you need Lookup fields (or children) you have to SOQL query them

```
opp.Primary_Contact__r.Id
```

Instead, change the line to

```
CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember(CampaignId = '7011a000000BBny',
                      ContactId = opp.Primary_Contact__c, Status = 'Sent');
```

*As an aside -- never use hard coded ids as they cause all sorts of deployment issues. Instead, query for the CampaignId*

Comment: Thanks! This works! Also thanks to @Vigneshwaran because he commented the same idea.

Comment: Also I was planning on changing the hard code ID, just put it there for now to make sure this would work. I will change before deployment.

Comment: @cmmoutes13 --good, Community tends to knee jerk (me included) when they see hard-coded IDs as they are really bad practice :-)  the after update idea is also meritorious.